# When Cassandra is running almost all RAM is consumed, why?

Tags: memory, configuration, cassandra

I have CentOS 6.8, Cassandra 3.9, 32 GB RAM. When I start Cassandra and once it is started, it starts consuming the memory and start adding up 'Cached' memory value when I start querying from CQLSH or Apache Spark and  in this process, very less memory remain for other processing like cron execution.

Here are some details from my system

```
free -m
         total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         32240      32003        237          0         41      24010
-/+ buffers/cache:       7950      24290
Swap:         2047         25       2022
```

And here is the output of top -M command

```
top - 08:54:39 up 5 days, 16:24,  4 users,  load average: 1.22, 1.20, 1.29
Tasks: 205 total,   2 running, 203 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  3.5%us,  1.2%sy, 19.8%ni, 75.3%id,  0.1%wa,  0.1%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:    31.485G total,   31.271G used,  219.410M free,   42.289M buffers
Swap: 2047.996M total,   25.867M used, 2022.129M free,   23.461G cached

PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
14313 cassandr  20   0  595g  28g  22g S 144.5 91.3 300:56.34 java
```

You can see only 220 MB is left and 23.46 is cached.

My question is how to configure Cassandra so that it can use 'cached' memory to certain value and leave more RAM available for other processes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the sizes in cassandra-env.sh under conf folder. This article should help. http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsTuneJVM.html

Answer (score 0):

Edit `/etc/cassandra/jvm.options` and set the desired values for memory consumption, e.g. `-Xms1G` and `-Xmx1G` if you want to give it just 1 Gb.

Note that the "cached" memory specifically can still be acquired by other processes. It's just sort of reserved, e.g. it's not so bad actually. But even the non-cached memory consumption of Cassandra is quite high, so for development without high workloads on Cassandra, you may want to configure the limits anyway.

Answer (score -1):

In linux in general cached memory as your 23g is just really fine. This memory is used as filesystem cache and so on - not by cassandra itself. Linux systems tend to use all available memory.

This helps to speed up your system in many ways to prevent disk reads.

You can still use the cached memory - just start processes and use your ram, the kernel will free it immediatly.

Comment: Hello @Jan, in my case when there is only 220 MB left (as shown in 'top' command, some of my queries start failing and I start getting errors in application. My crons starts failing. Any idea why that happens? because if more memory is available then everything works.

Comment: Strange - you can tune cassandras JVM:

http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsTuneJVM.html

Comment: "Linux systems tend to use all available memory" - that is not true. It really depends on the apps that you're using, and an out-of-the-box system tends to do the exact opposite. For example, randomly looking right now at my desktop with a running Firefox, Slack, some terminals and stuff like that -- more than half is free and not used at all. Databases, on the other hand, tend to absorb all the memory they can, yes. (Including memory-efficient DBs like Postgres). On top of that, cassandra is *especially* memory-hungry, not willing to start at all with medium resources.

Comment: @VasiliNovikov what I meant was, Linux will use as much memory when available - not for your applications, but if there is free memory not used by them, the kernel will use the memory for filesystem caches and buffers, which will fee when memory is needed otherwise.